# pyspark flatten multi parent hierarchy into a single column

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parent-child, hierarchical-clustering

I have a node - > parent_node dataset in the following format. I need to generate a node_map so that any query trying to select the 'node' or 'any of it parents' results in a matching record.

It appears simple enough but I am unable to get this done in a simple way in pyspark. Number of levels of parents is upto 9(below example has a depth 2 and 3), so a self join solution looks very clumsy.

Thank you for looking into this.

Input dataframe

```
---------------------------------
|node           |   parent_node |
---------------------------------
|pl3182020828   |   NULL        |
|pl3182020830   |   pl3182020828|
|pl3182020829   |   pl3182020830|
|l66434         |   pl3182020829|
|l66435         |   pl3182020829|
|pl3182020832   |   NULL        |
|pl3182020831   |   pl3182020832|
|l66900         |   pl3182020831|
|pl3182020833   |   pl3182020832|
|l66916         |   pl3182020833|
---------------------------------
```

Expected output dataframe

```
---------------------------------------------------------
|node   |node_map                                        |
---------------------------------------------------------
|l66434 |[l66434,pl3182020829,pl3182020830,pl3182020828 ]|
|l66435 |[l66435,pl3182020829,pl3182020830,pl3182020828] |
|l66900 |[l66900,pl3182020831,pl3182020832]              |
|l66916 |[l66916,pl3182020833,pl3182020832]              |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: How large is the data size?

Comment: about 100K child nodes